# What are these subgroups called?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Let $S \subset G$. Consider the set of all $x \in G$ such that $xS = S$.
What is this unique largest subgroup of $G$ preserving $S$ under left-multiplication called?
(As for the plural used in the title, there is an analogous subgroup for right-multiplication.)

Comment: Why isn't this just the subgroup of all $k$ such that $kS = S$ (so the stabilizer of $S$ in $2^G$)?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is. I logged in because I just realized this.

Comment: (And I removed superfluous elements of my reasoning.)

Answer (score 2):

It is the set-wise stabilizer of $S$ under the left regular action.